# What is the purpose of the Normal Matcap?

Tags: matcaps

What is the use of the **normal matcap**. What does it help to check in a scene or model?
[image]

Comment: I guess you can quickly make a normal map with a simple screenshot but there must be other purposes

Comment: I don't think matcaps have a "purpose" like that-- they are good for visualizing your mesh in a way that shows its normals, but that's the case for all of them, and this one is not the best for that in my opinion.  However, a normal map matcap is a very easy way to display your normals in a *still* for purposes of sharing on a market site or something.

Comment: Ok... yeah maybe that is the case. I once saw a video (many months ago) where the artist used the Normal Matcap for checking if everything is flush to the ground *or* things don't look afloat. I was confused with it but he never explained.. I asked but never got an answer. @moonboots

Comment: Four of the matcaps including the normal one are for "geometry checking" (click [here](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/call-for-content-matcaps/737/228) and scroll down a bit) to make sure you're normals look right I guess.

Comment: It is most commonly used for sculpting, as it gives quick and useful feedback on how an objects shape is changing.